# Did Eric Morecambe have plans for a third book in the "Reluctant Vampire" series?

Tags: books, sequel

Thanks to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215914/105070, I reconnected with a hard-to-find, well-loved book from my childhood.

**Did Eric Morecambe have any plans for a third book in his *The Reluctant Vampire* series?**
The end of the second book seems to have left open the possibility of a return of the series' main antagonist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Eric Morecambe did indeed have plans for a third vampire book. From the biography *Eric Morecambe: Life's Not Hollywood It's Cricklewood*, written by his son Gary:

> EM [Eric Morecambe] wrote two vampire stories for children. *The
> Reluctant Vampire* was followed by *The Vampire's Revenge*, and
> **he'd planned a third title**, *The Vampire King*, which I completed after his
> death (although it was only ever published in Denmark)

Thanks to google translate, here is a summary of the plot from a [Danish library](https://bibliotek.dk/da/work/870970-basis%3A21585939):

> The third part of the story about the famous vampire family at
>  Blodborg Castle, which looms ominously on the mountain above the
>  village of Biddem-i-halsen in the small principality of Fangdem. The
>  first two books, *The Reluctant Vampire* from 1984 and T*he Vampire's
>  Revenge* from 1988, were written by Eric Morecambe. After his death,
>  his son Gary completed this third book. The vampire Vernon returns
>  after being shot into space by a cannon 30 years earlier. All he has
>  in mind is his cruel revenge on those who opposed him back then. We
>  follow him and his opponents during the preparations and execution of
>  a "reconciliation party" at Blodborg Castle. In fact, this is where
>  Vernon will take the final revenge - namely, turning them all into
>  golden statues. However, once again ex-president Valentine, Areta,
>  Egon and Villy Werewolf manage to get rid of Vernon.

Comment: OMG: I have a new mission in life: to find this almost-certainly-hard-to-find third book in the series!

Comment: It's listed in Danish libraries (published in 1997), but you may have to learn Danish to read it ;)

Comment: The good news is a lot of smartphones will (Google) translate it in close to realtime through the camera.